# Using adapters in JavaScript Use-API in Sightly

Tags: aem, sightly

I have a path and want to adapt it into Page using Sightly.

The user can enter a path in the dialog — 
in my logic, I am using `currentPage` as a default value,  but if the user enters a path, I want to use this instead.

How can I change the path into a `Page` object in JavaScript, in order to use all functions of the Page API? (i.e. I'm using JavaScript for my backing logic rather than Java)

Comment: You need ask specific question about issue you are facing? What code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Shivani, I've tried to clarify what you meant in the question & make it a little easier to read. If I misinterpreted, please feel free to roll-back my edit or edit over the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PageManager is implicitly available as a pre-defined object in the JavaScript Use-API (`pageManager`), that you can go ahead & use.

E.g, if you had a variable `path`, and wanted to resolve the relevant page & return its title, you could do:

```
use(function () {
    var path ="/content/foo/bar";
    return {
        pageTitle: pageManager.getPage(path).title
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks anotherdave. Exactly this is what i am looking for.Really helpful